# Does the REST API provide an equivalent method for the SOAP API's retrieve() method?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, rest, soap

The SOAP API supports a "retrieve()" method that returns all records whose ID's are in some given list of ID's. Is there an equivalent in the REST API?

The closest I could find was https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm but that only allows me to specify a single ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) resource to execute a SOQL query via REST API that returns all the results in a single response. You can append all the ids in a comma separated list as below. But Salesforce has a limitation of 4,000 characters for Maximum length of SOQL WHERE clause.

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account+WHERE+Id+In+('001i000000gDY4a','001i000000gDY4c')
```

Comment: Thanks Saroj for the response.

If the character limit is an issue, do you think I can use the Composite API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm to make a series of such Query requests? That way, if the number of ID's I want to retrieve exceeds the character limit, I can partition the list into sublists and make the Query request for each sublist within a Composite API call.